# Display result without duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my sample database.

```
1)base_groups
|base_gp_id| base_gp_name  |
----------------------------
|    1     |   Technician  | 
|    2     |   Sales       | 
|    3     |   R&D         |
|    4     |   Testing     | 

2)base_subgroup
                            (FK of base_groups)
| base_id  |   base_name   |    base_gp_id    |
-----------------------------------------------
|    1     |    group1     |    1, 2, 3       |
|    2     |    group2     |       3          | 
|    3     |    group3     |      3, 4        |
```

My question is how am I going to display the group name only **once**. Thanks in advance. 
 Here is my code and the result.

```
<?php
//$groupInfo consists of base_subgroup ID : 1,2 and 3
foreach($groupInfo as $value)
{
    $group_sql = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM base_subgroup WHERE base_name='".$value."'");
    while($row = base_fetch_array($group_sql))
    if(base_num_rows($group_sql) != 0)
    {
        $group_data = explode(", ",$row['base_gp_id']);

        foreach($group_data as $data)
        {
            $group_query = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM base_groups WHERE base_gp_id='".$data."'");
            while($row_group = base_fetch_array($group_query))              
                echo $row_group['base_gp_name'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the code above:

```
Technician
Sales
R&D
R&D
R&D
Testing
```

But this is the result that I have to show:

```
Technican
Sales
R&D
Testing
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` should do the trick

Comment: Storing FK's as csv is very bad db design! You should change it

Comment: @Jens I know it is a very bad design, but I have to follow the previous system design with the minimum change due to time constraints.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans It doesn't work. I tried that before.

Comment: Why it shows all the base group name, from the given data if the `$value` is `group1` then it should not have `Testing` right ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Since the user is belong to these three groups, so it will show group `Testing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

```
$group_data = array();
foreach($groupInfo as $value)
{
    $group_sql = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM base_subgroup WHERE base_name='".$value."'");

    while($row = base_fetch_array($group_sql))
    if(base_num_rows($group_sql) != 0)
    {
        $group_data = array_merge($group_data, explode(", ",$row['base_gp_id']));
    }
}
$group_data = array_unique($group_data);
$group_query = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM base_groups WHERE base_gp_id IN (". implode(',', $group_data) .")");
while($row_group = base_fetch_array($group_query)) {              
    echo $row_group['base_gp_name'] . "<br>";
}
```

When you need a single column to work with then dont fetch them with `*`, use fetch that column only..

**Previously**

Add a `Group By` clause. It will fetch unique result from the database. Try with -

```
"SELECT * FROM base_groups WHERE base_gp_id='".$data."' GROUP BY base_gp_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using mysql**, here is a very simpler solution:

```
  <?php
    //$groupInfo consists of base_subgroup ID : 1,2 and 3
    foreach($groupInfo as $value)
    {
        $res = base_executeSQL("SELECT t2.* FROM `base_subgroup` t1 JOIN `base_groups` t2 ON LOCATE(CONCAT(',',t2.base_gp_id,','), CONCAT(',',t1.base_gp_id,','))>0 WHERE t1.base_name='".$value."' GROUP BY t2.base_gp_id");
        while($row = base_fetch_array($res))
            echo $row['base_gp_name'] . "<br>";
    }
```

Attention that I assumed there is no space between CSV list stored in base_subgroup table.
If you are using any relational database other than mysql, you should use equivalents for `CONCAT` & `LOCATE` functions.